# Commerce 3: How to programmatically create a custom field and assign it to a Product

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

With this kind of setup:

```php
function random()
{
    return array_reduce(range(0, 9), fn ($x) => $x . range('a', 'z')[rand(0, 25)], '');
}

$salt = random();

$result = Craft::$app->getFields()->saveField($field = new craft\fields\Number([
    'handle' => $salt,
    'name' => $salt,
]));
assert($result === true);
```

I can add this field to a `User`:

```php
$result = Craft::$app->getFields()->saveLayout(new craft\models\FieldLayout([
    'fields' => [$field],
    'type' => craft\elements\User::class,
]));
assert($result === true);

$result = Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($user = new craft\elements\User([
    'email' => "$salt@domain.com",
    'username' => $salt,
    $salt => 42,
]));
assert($result === true);
assert($user->{$salt} === 42);
assert(Craft::$app->getElements()->getElementById($user->id, craft\elements\User::class)->{$salt} === 42);
```

and to an `Order`:

```php
$result = Craft::$app->getFields()->saveLayout(new craft\models\FieldLayout([
    'fields' => [$field],
    'type' => craft\commerce\elements\Order::class,
]));
assert($result === true);

$result = Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($order = new craft\commerce\elements\Order([
    $salt => 42,
]));
assert($result);
assert($order->{$salt} === 42);
assert(Craft::$app->getElements()->getElementById($order->id, craft\commerce\elements\Order::class)->{$salt} === 42);
```

but I cannot do the same with a `Product`:

```php
$result = Craft::$app->getFields()->saveLayout(new craft\models\FieldLayout([
    'fields' => [$field],
    'type' => craft\commerce\elements\Product::class,
]));
assert($result === true);

$result = craft\commerce\Plugin::getInstance()->getProductTypes()->saveProductType($productType = new craft\commerce\models\ProductType([
    'handle' => $salt,
    'hasDimensions' => false,
    'hasVariants' => false,
    'name' => $salt,
    'siteSettings' => [
        Craft::$app->getSites()->getCurrentSite()->id => new craft\commerce\models\ProductTypeSite(),
    ],
]));
assert($result === true);

$result = Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($product = new craft\commerce\elements\Product([
    'slug' => $salt,
    'title' => $salt,
    'typeId' => $productType->id,
    'variants' => [
        [
            'hasUnlimitedStock' => false,
            'price' => 0,
            'maxQty' => 0,
            'minQty' => 0,
        ],
    ],
    $salt => 42,
]));
assert($result === true);
assert($product->{$salt} === 42);
assert(Craft::$app->getElements()->getElementById($product->id, craft\commerce\elements\Product::class)->{$salt} === 42);
```

Both assertions fail (though the `Product` is saved without errors), so I'm assuming I am missing some additional piece of ceremony in the creation. What could that be?

Comment: Whats the result of `Plugin::getInstance()->getProductTypes()->saveProductType`?

Comment: @LukeHolder a fair question. I've added assertions on the results of each call; they all return `true`. In preparing the test case, I also checked the errors (`assert(!$x->hasErrors());`) for each created item, they also passed.